# Tensorflow 0.10 (CUDA) on OSX segfaults on python import

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I've been trying to get tensorflow 0.10 up and running on my El Capitan Macbook Pro (Late 2013, GeForce GT 750M), so far without success. I've tried the [official tensorflow documentation's instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html) and a number of other folks' approaches, including [this one](https://gist.github.com/Mistobaan/dd32287eeb6859c6668d) and [this one](https://medium.com/@fabmilo/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-cuda-support-on-osx-fd27108e27e1#.eww7dgmtr).

For reference, I'm trying to use Python3, CUDA 7.5, and tensorflow 0.10 on OSX 10.11.5.

I've gotten CUDA installed and it recognizes my GPU. I can successfully compile the `deviceQuery` sample in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`. Its output when run is:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 750M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          7.5 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147024896 bytes)
  ( 2) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            926 MHz (0.93 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2508 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 262144 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.5, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GT 750M
Result = PASS
```

I've also downloaded the cudnn-7.5 library and header and put those files in the correct locations in `/usr/local/cuda/lib` and `include`.

In the python3 interactive REPL, if I type in `import tensorflow`, I get the following output:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.7.5.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.5.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.7.5.dylib locally
Segmentation fault: 11
```

My question is, what do I need to do to successfully import the module without a segfault? In case it helps, I posted a gist of the `dtruss` output of running that command in the python3 REPL [here](https://gist.github.com/danielthompson/617b093177f49c15d1dfb4d656c3b036), and a gist of the diagnostic (crash) report with stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/danielthompson/26fde46af631ddf3b3df3e86393750ab).

Comment: Can you get a stack trace as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3723#issuecomment-239175762)

Comment: Edited to include that.

Comment: Can you see if this solution works? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2940#issuecomment-238952433

Comment: Yep... that seems to have done it. Add an answer here and I'll accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is described in this comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2940#issuecomment-238952433

"There is a bug with loading libcuda.dylib - the default cuda install creates libcuda.dylib, but tensorflow tries to load libcuda.1.dylib . This fails, resorting to using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH which if NULL crashes. If you copy libcuda.dylib to libcuda.1.dylib it loads fine."

It would be pretty easy to fix the crash for everyone else with a pull request -- ie compile with `-c dbg` to see exactly which line is trying to use the null value, and adding something like this to the code

`if (mystring == NULL) {
  return;
}`